# org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: protoc failure

Tags: java, maven, hadoop

I meet some problems when i use maven to complie hadoop from  source code.Here is the error, can  anyone help me? Thanks.

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-maven-plugins:3.0.0-SNAPSHOT:protoc (compile-protoc) on project hadoop-c
 [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-maven-plugins:3.0.0-SNAP
plugin.MojoExecutionException: protoc failure
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:217)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: protoc failure
        at org.apache.hadoop.maven.plugin.protoc.ProtocMojo.execute(ProtocMojo.java:81)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
        ... 19 more
**Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: protoc failure**
        at org.apache.hadoop.maven.plugin.protoc.ProtocMojo.execute(ProtocMojo.java:78)
        ... 21 more
[ERROR]
[ERROR]
```

Comment: sorry, i am a new guy. I try to turn it to code format, but it's failed.

Comment: Why do you need to compile Hadoop from source?

Answer (score 13):

The instructions at http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/HowToContribute explain some of the less obvious aspects of building hadoop - including this one. **The main problem here is that Protocol Buffers are required by hadoop's YARN framework, and you most likely do not have them installed.**

It seems like the problem might be that your not interpretting the error correctly, so --

**How to Isolate the Build error**

Any mojo which fails should be associated with a class.

In this case, the mojo that is failing is here :

https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/hadoop/common/trunk/hadoop-maven-plugins/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/maven/plugin/protoc/ProtocMojo.java

Looking at the code, its clear that this Mojo requires the "protoc" program to run.

http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/

**Solution**

To build hadoop, you need protocol buffers.  This can be installed on a *NIX machine from source, by running the following commands to grab the code from googlecode (taken from http://numbers.brighterplanet.com/2012/04/14/how-to-install-mosh-on-amazon-ec2/).

```
wget http://protobuf.googlecode.com/files/protobuf-2.4.1.tar.gz
tar xzf protobuf-2.4.1.tar.gz
cd protobuf-2.4.1
./configure
make
sudo make install
sudo ldconfig
```

Comment: Update: trunk now requires protobuf 2.5: `wget http://protobuf.googlecode.com/files/protobuf-2.5.0.tar.gz`

Comment: How do you compile this on a windows?

Comment: @Sambit Tripathy: To get this for Windows, go to https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/downloads and get the Windows Binary. You just add the path to protoc.exe in your environment PATH, and it will be installed! For the Hadoop for Eclipse installation package I got from Apache Nutch site, 2.5.0 version is needed, so get that one only, and you are all set!